# Can wireshark tell me the ip AND subnet a device is on?

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have a device that I do not know the IP **or** the subnet that it is on. Can wireshark tell me both of these things? I **think** the ip is somewhere around 10.3.253.x....just dont know for sure, and most importantly I dont know what subnet it is on.....help :/

Answer (score 1):

No, not explicitly. The netmask is used only when deciding how to deal with routers and broadcast addresses, and isn't sent over the wire at any point. If you could see all traffic from the device, you could infer the subnet by seeing for what IPs it routes data for (for instance, ICMP ping replies).

Comment: I am trying to access a Lantronix device.....or atleast, resetting it back to default. Anyone know how to do this?...again, I dont know the ip...

Comment: @user1578089: The Lantronix device installer has a configuration setup tool which will take the MAC (physical address) of the device - unfortunately it works about 1/3rd of the time. Barring that, there is a serial console available on one of the serial ports (try holding 'x' as it reboots at 9600 baud). I hate Lantronix devices.

Comment: Yeah, tried holding x in hyperterminal....nothing, just a blank screen. I confirmed that the serial adapter is working via the loop method and it is. I cannot get the device to talk with hyperterminal at all. All appears setup correctly. Any advice?..